# Blank page laravel

Tags: laravel

Larave displays a white page, storage is 777, bootstrap is 777, I have .env working, I did a composer update, my htacess

It does not show any error in php.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Does the storage/logs/laravel.log file say anything?

Comment: #19 /home/jysparki/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /home/jysparki/public_html/artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 {main}   But i did composer update and it worked well

Comment: Please copy&paste the full log entry (not only line 19-21) to your initial question using the edit button. It's way more readable then :)

Comment: When you say you did a "composer update and it worked well", does this mean you're no longer having the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try use the default Laravel htaccess ?

Try use this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```